# Parabolic elements and hyperbolic elements in SL(2,R)

Tags: gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices

Let $\Gamma \subset \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ be a lattice. If $N_1, N_2$ are a pair of independent parabolic subgroups contained in $\Gamma$, why must $\Gamma$ contain a hyperbolic element? By parabolic subgroup, I mean "subgroup containing only parabolic elements, other than the identity." This is used in the proof of Theorem 10.1, here:

[https://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/abel/abel.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ectm/papers/home/text/papers/abel/abel.pdf)

If it helps, $\Gamma$ here is the stabilizer of a 1-form defining a Teichmuller curve.

Comment: The point is that, and this is true in any Gromov-hyperbolic space, the product of two (high powers of) independent parabolic isometries is loxodromic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very special case follows from "general principles" (namely a version of the ping-pong lemma) but it is also possible to give a direct proof, as follows.

---

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are the distinct points at infinity fixed by the two parabolic subgroups $A$ and $B$ (note change of notation).  Since $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is three-transitive, we can conjugate $\Gamma$ and so assume that $a = \infty$ and $b = 0$. We deduce that elements of $A$ now have the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & r\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
while elements of $B$ have the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
s & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Taking an inverse if needed, we obtain such elements of $A$ and $B$ where $r$ and $s$ are non-zero and have the same sign.  We now multiply to find
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & r\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
s & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 + rs & r\\
s & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This has trace $2 + rs > 2$ so is hyperbolic, as desired.

---

Hmm.  Now that I write this, I realise that there is a third proof using the classification of fixed points of isometries, and the intermediate value theorem. It helps to draw a picture and think dynamically.

Comment: Great, I was wanting something like this, as pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphisms have derivatives with trace larger than 2, and you can produce any one of these (Thurston) from a product of parabolic elements

Comment: It is not true that all pA maps arise from the Thurston-Veech construction. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6974

Comment: I see. But you can produce pA diffeomorphisms from a product of two transverse parabolic elements, using the Thurston-Veech construction, correct ?

Comment: Yes, some pA maps arise in this way.  In particular, if you have a flat surface that decomposes nicely (in two ways) as a union of annuli with rationally related moduli, then the right twist (aka shear) on one, followed by the left twist on the other, will be pA.  The Thurston--Veech construction is usually phrased as a special case of this, where the flat surface is tiled by squares.

Comment: Is it possible to give a similarly elementary argument to prove the same statement in dim>2?

Comment: @Dinisaur - In dimension three the argument is extremely similar (including the "shapes" of the matrices).